# ASP.Net Core C# Select Option Redirect Change Selected Option

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-core

I have been able to Sort Ascending and Descending by Name and Price in my ASP.Net Core application which I am happy with. I am using a HTML select and returning the option to the Controller which works perfectly.
*My only gripe* is that every time I click one of the options it still defaults to the first option:

```
<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
            <option value="@Url.Action("Spain", new {order="name"})">
                Name Ascending (A-Z)
            </option>
            <option value="@Url.Action("Spain", new {order="name_desc"})">
                Name Descending (Z-A)
            </option>
            <option value="@Url.Action("Spain", new {order="price"})">
                Price Ascending (€)
            </option>
            <option value="@Url.Action("Spain", new {order="price_desc"})">
                Price Descending (€)
            </option>
        </select>
```

I would like it to change the selected option on page load to the one I just selected to sort the objects. I understand that this is complicated by the fact that I am technically redirecting to a new page but I can't seem to achieve what I want with jQuery or even base JS as it does not register the `?order=name_desc` etc. in the URL.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `onchange` event of `select` you can pass the selected index to action:

```
<select id="select1" onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value+'&selectedIndex='+this.options[this.selectedIndex].index);">
```

In action , get the index from query string , send to view using  Viewbag :

```
public ActionResult Spain(string order ,string selectedIndex)       
{
    ....
    ViewBag.selectedIndex = selectedIndex;
    return View();
}
```

In that page , after loading the DOM , you can set the selected index value using JQuery :

```
@section Scripts{ 
    <script>
        $(function () {            
            if (@ViewBag.selectedIndex !=null) {
                $("#select1").prop('selectedIndex', @ViewBag.selectedIndex);
            }

        })
    </script>
}
```